# What are some options to execute ML algos against with live data using C#, F# or Python for a retail trader?

Tags: market-data

I'm a retail algorithmic trader.  I've written some algorithms that parse intraday movements and make decisions.  I still execute trades manually but eventually I need the ability to execute trades on the fly.

I need a platform where I can implement these algos in C#, F#, Java or Python against live data feeds to flag the situations.

Obviously, TD Ameritrade has Thinkscript but it's not really what I need.  I need to be able to use regular programming languages against live data.

Any ideas?

Comment: We are building a co-located datacenter platform that submits trades via Ameritrade accounts. If you want to collaborate, shoot me an email to post at armada hyphen hft.com.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that by "retail trader", you mean that the limitations are: (1) broker with low account minimum balance requirement, and (2) software with low to zero license fees.

In that case, you could use the following:

1. IB: [Interactive Brokers API](https://www.interactivebrokers.com/en/index.php?f=5041). Native support for Java, C# .NET and C++.
2. Lightspeed: [Lightspeed Trader API](https://www.lightspeedinstitutional.com/automated-trading/lightspeed-trader-api/). Native support for C++.
3. Broker-neutral: [Rithmic R | API](http://www3.rithmic.com/?page_id=9). Native support for C++ and C# .NET.
4. Broker-neutral: [TT X_TRADER Pro API/FIX Adapter](https://developer.tradingtechnologies.com/choose-api). Native support for C# .NET.
5. NinjaTrader Brokerage: [NinjaTrader](http://www.ninjatraderbrokerage.com/). Native support for C# .NET.
6. Broker-neutral: [CQG](http://www.cqg.com/products/cqg-apis). Native support for managed C++ and C# .NET.

All of the above expose a higher-level interface to live market data and order execution.